# If a character were to live in a hot climate for the majority of their life, would their core temperature increase?

Tags: post-apocalypse, climate, apocalypse, temperature

I'm making a comic about the apocalypse and I have a character who lives in Australia for most of his life. The thing is, global warming has caused Australia to increase in temperature so much, it's almost inhospitable.

Wild fires break out a lot and you start sweating as soon at you get near the country. The character in question would have had to have some kind of evolution in order for him to survive.

My theory was that his core temperature would increase, because if it's closer to the environment's temperature, there would be less of a chance for him to get hurt. And if my hypothesis is correct, it would mean he is more susceptible to the cold, and is at a higher risk for hypothermia in lower climates. I tried googling for the answer but found nothing, so I decided to come here and ask.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me. Even if you don't have facts or evidence, anything you say will be a great help!

(EDIT: I feel like I should mention the fact that the characters family has lived in Australia of a while, and that the only reason I put down "most of his life" if because he moves halfway through the story. I can understand where there would be confusion. I know that evolution cannot happen in one's lifetime, but if there were to be several generations of people before you, could my theory be possible?)

Comment: (1) Most of the territory of Australia already is inhospitable. (2) Millions of people have lived in the Sahara for millennia, and yet Berbers and Touaregs have the same core temperature as everybody else. (3) Evolution does not happen with the lifespan of an individual. Natural evolution 101: individuals do not evolve; *populations* do. (4) That's not how hypothermia happens. (Core body temperature is one of the fundamental conditions for the intricate biochemistry which makes an animal tick; changing those fundamental conditions is possible only over millions of years.)

Comment: @AlexP, while your point (3) is correct, people's bodies *do* change over their life (fat, muscle and bone mass, metabolism), sometimes even over the span of a few days. Core temperature is affected by e.g. illness. I'm far from convinced it can't also be affected by environment. Also, your point about mean core temperatures only changing over millions of years is... questionable. According to at least [one source](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/are-human-body-temperatures-cooling-down/), we've seen changes in just a few generations.

Comment: @Matthew: Yeah, that source. (Opinion about that source deleted.) Nobody was measuring core temperatures one hundred and fifty years ago, for the simple reason that they couldn't, not unless they were willing to kill their pacients in the process. They were measuring external temperatures, and those do indeed vary. (And I assume that the question was about noticeable change, not about the half degree centigrade, or about one degree Farrenhyte which is perfectly normal, and corresponds to different sexes, points in the circadian rhythm, levels of effort and environmental conditions.)

Answer (score 5):

Humans have been living in extreme locations like the polar regions, Tibetans mountains and Australian bush for long enough to develop genetic adaptations to those environments.

None of them has involved a change in their core temperature. Therefore I would say that also your scenario is unlikely to happen.

This doesn't mean the character will be less subject to cold damage: a taller and slender figure works worse than a shorter and more rounded one in saving energy from being lost to the outside, therefore increase susceptibility to cold is very likely.

Comment: ...which is not to say mean body temperature isn't subject to change; interestingly, [it may be going down](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/are-human-body-temperatures-cooling-down/)...

Answer (score 2):

**They can't**

The reason for our temperature is independent of the outside temperature. Warm blooded animals have certain enzymes that make it possible to be active during any time of the day. Cold blooded animals are more dependent on the amount of heat their environment is for how active and fast they can be.

Most of the enzymes work best around 37 degrees C. Most start to function badly or might even break down into something else if the heat is over 40 degrees C. Raising a core temperature would be highly unlikely, as it would require a whole different set of enzymes for identical functions.

What is more plausible is better ways to lose heat to stay at a healthy core temperature, or ways to deflect heat. But we're already very adept at this as humans via clothing and shelter. If neither of those exist, several other options might be available. Better sweating (on which humans are already nr 1 if I don't miss my guess), reflective skin or maybe a way to reduce heat production from normal functioning. Some are more plausible than others, as a reflective skin would take many more generations to develop than a more efficient sweating system.

Answer (score 1):

No - our body processes need core temperature in a certain range.

If left to the wild without our society to protect us, we may evolve to get better at sweating, we may evolve better fluid management strategies, but our internal core temperature wont change without substantial other changes to our physiology. And if we have shelter and air con none of these evolutionary changes will happen.

A core temperature increase is a medical condition - hyperthermia - causes half a million deaths per year according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperthermia.

Of course it could happen for other reasons: Your core temperature may go up to help you fight infection, and a post-apocalypse Australia will probably be an infection hazard.

As an Australian, I would like to point out that Australia is already mostly inhospitable due to climate change.

- My city hit 47.7 degrees C last summer. A new record. The old record was from the year before.
- A city with a population in millions got ringed by fire and held under seige for days.
- [57% of the adult population were affected by bushfire smoke this year](https://www.abc.net.au/news/science/2020-03-05/bushfire-crisis-five-big-numbers/12007716#:%7E:text=11.3%20million%20Australians%20affected%20by%20smoke&text=Professor%20Biddle%20from%20the%20Australian,by%20smoke%20from%20the%20bushfires.)
- Thousands of tourists spent their new years eve in neck deep water because a bushfire burnt through a town all the way to the water.

... [and our government is still investing in coal.](https://www.theguardian.com/australia-news/2020/feb/08/private-investors-wont-touch-new-coalition-backed-coal-plant-labor-says)